# cannot run celery subtasks if queues are specified

Tags: celery

I am running celery 3.0.19 with mongodb as backend and broker. I would like to use queues in sub-tasks but it does not work.  Here is how to reproduce the problem from the example `add` task.

Start a celery worker with the command

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --queue=foo
```

Then create a task that never gets done like that

```
from tasks import add
sub_task = add.s(queue="foo")
sub_task_async_result = sub_task.apply_async((2,2))
```

note the following task will get executed normally.

```
async_result = add.apply_async((2,2), queue="foo")
```

what do I do wrong?

Thanks!